# ¿Cómo podría hacer un método que me muestra un nodo según la posición ingresada?

Tags: c#

Esto es lo que he intentado hacer, crear dos punteros para poder recorrer al siguiente nodo

```
public int Ver(int pos)
{
    Nodo auxiliar = new Nodo();
    Nodo puntero;
   
    puntero = inicio;
   
    if (pos == 1)
    {
        inicio = auxiliar;
        auxiliar.Siguiente = puntero;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < pos - 1; i++)
        {
            puntero = puntero.Siguiente;
            if (puntero.Siguiente == null)
                break;
          
        }
        Nodo punteronext;
        punteronext = puntero.Siguiente;
        puntero.Siguiente = auxiliar;
        auxiliar.Siguiente = punteronext;
    }
    return pos;
```

Comment: Debes retornar un nodo si quieres obtener un nodo según su posición. La pregunta no parece muy clara. El código parece tomar un rumbo diferente al de la pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a SO en español!  Por favor, léete [ask] y realiza el [tour] para aprender a formular preguntas que sean mejor aceptadas por la comunidad. Tal como está ahora carece de un [example] y es dificil de entender. Contesta los comentarios solicitando información adicional y si conviene puedes [edit] tu pregunta tantas veces como sea necesario para mejorarla. Gracias por colaborar en el buen funcionamiento del sitio!